# How to avoid FATAL error in Smarty templates while we check for objects

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am performing the following check in a Smarty template:

```
{{if $Pricing->getCommission()}}
    do something
{{/if}}
```

This is part of the class `Pricing`:

```
class Pricing {
    ...
    protected $commission;

    public function getCommission() {
        return $this->commission;
    }
}

$Pricing = new Pricing();
```

Then I use the `$Pricing` PHP object in the Smarty template. If `$Pricing` lacks of `commission` property, accessed through `getCommission()` public method this will turn into a FATAL and the application will thrown this to the view or in the best case display a blank page. I want to avoid that, how? I can't change how values are received meaning I can't get rid of the object on the template. Any advice?

Comment: you can use condition inside the `getCommission` function.

Comment: @RohitKishore you mean ... in the PHP side? or? sorry I am not following you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `isset` condition around your statement such as

```
{{if isset($Pricing->Commission)}} ...
```

Note that Commission must be a public property. Otherwise you should do as stated in the comment and add a check inside the `getCommission` method

Comment: Same comment as before .... can you show me the full statement with the `getCommission()` conditional? I am not following you neither

Comment: So you can't do the `isset` option ?

Comment: `Commission` isn't a property, is a public method, check the `get` before ;)

Comment: OK then something is wrong in your description it says "If $Pricing lacks of Commission object|property", could you give us more details about the code so that we can help you out ? The `get` before does not imply that there is a `Commission` property available, it just states that `getCommission()` is a method provided by the `$Pricing` object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121739/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-kartsims).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
{{if $Pricing && $Pricing->getCommission()}}
    do something
{{/if}}
```

That way I will be checking if `$Pricing` is not null and if `$Pricing->getCommission()` is not null either.